# Can Gelly Library be used for graph queries in Flink similar to Graph Frame in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-flink, graphframes, gelly

Can Flink graph library Gelly do graph partitioning, graph pattern matching, joins, etc ..

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to read the [Gelly documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/libs/gelly/). It lists all available operations and algorithms. You can also find some examples [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/release-1.4/flink-libraries/flink-gelly-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/graph/examples).